# Subsonic 3 SimpleRepository NON Plural Table names?

Tags: subsonic3

Is it possible to use SubSonic 3's Simple Repository with non-plural table names?  My DB already exists, the table names a re singular add I cannot change them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, it is hardcoded in the SubSonic's source.  You can pull it down and trace the migration steps to see where the plural happens.  I know, cause I wanted the same thing.

I was tinkering with modifying the source to make plurals optional via some parameter/config override or alike.  But, I didn't get it completed (yet).

Comment: Crap, that stinks.  I have the same issue.

Comment: Double Crap I have the same problem from a database I am working on

Comment: +1s for the both of you. I've since moved to (and so has Rob) Entity Framework 4, with the POCO Templates option. Extremely easy and very clean Designer that works completely now.

Answer (score 0):

If your tables already exist then this is not the intended use of the Simple Repository model. The simple repository model is designed to generate the table structures for you using migrations.

If you are using a database that already exists then you would be better served using the T4 Templates as they also support the relationships between your tables.

Cheers,

Ed

Answer (score 0):

With Subsonic 3.0.0.4 in the `settings.ttinclude` I removed the line;

```
AddSingularRule("s$", String.Empty);
```

which was down about 260 lines in the `Inflector` rules class. Didn't need to mess around with the subsonic source code.

HTH