# How to use SubSonic SimpleRepository with NON Plural Table Names

Tags: subsonic, subsonic3

I have found out that SubSonic SimpleRepository expectes plural table names however I have started working on a database that doesn't have this and I am unable to change the table names.

Is there a way I can use Subsonic without making database changes?

I have seen [one suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1780906/subsonic-3-simplerepository-non-plural-table-names/1780982#1780982) but I don't fancy that too much.

I'm not tied to using the SimpleRepository I just thought it would be easiest as I need the ability to swap database connections (SQL & Oracle) based on the clients requirements.  The schema is the same on both.  With SimpleRepository I can just swap out the connection string in the web.config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply the SubSonicTableNameOverride attribute on your classes you use with Simple Repo and use an arbitrary table name!

Comment: Thanks. Can you confirm that SubSonic SimpleRepository works with Oracle?

Comment: I added the attribute then run against Oracle and it says the table doesnt exist. However if I use the CodingHorror class back door for inline SQL it does execute a SELECT statement.

Comment: also using it against a SQL Server with the attribute works fine. I think this must be a issue with it using Oracle